# Burninate the [positioning] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Reasons to burninate [positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/positioning):

1. You could be positioning anything. (`<div>` elements, unicorns, etc.)
2. There is no such thing as a positioning expert. (Within the realm of programming)
3. The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/positioning/info) already says `"This tag is ambiguous. DO NOT USE THIS TAG."` However, based on the number of [recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/positioning?sort=newest&pageSize=50), users don't look at the tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: ...And there is [position as well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274752/position-and-css-position)

Comment: I think at least it could be made a synonym to [tag:position]

Answer (score 3):

Burninating the tag doesn't seem like a good way to me. I'd suggest to clean up [these 656 questions which are not CSS-related](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpositioning%5D+-%5Bcss%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano&mixed=0) [as mentioned](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47268397#47268397) by Bhargav Rao and the rest, which are CSS-related should be synonymized with [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position). This will reduce the amount of effort people who participate in burns put. It's worth noting that a synonym of [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position) is [css-positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-positioning).

I disagree with Vadim Kotov. The [positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/positioning) tag shouldn't be a synonym of [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position). The [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position) tag is too broad on its own and adding 2.5k questions in it will just make things worse.