# Position and css-position tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I came across [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position) tag in a CSS question. I thought it is too general and it should be something like [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position), and found that it already exists.

The excerpt of [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position) is as follows:

> Position refers to the location of an element relative to its container, typically on the horizontal and vertical axes.

This sounds very much like positioning [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) elements.

But, the description of [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position) is something too generic:

> In computing, position closely relates to the geometrical definition of a position or position vector, also known as location vector or radius vector, which is a Euclidean vector that represents the position of a point P in space in relation to an arbitrary reference origin O. Usually denoted x, r or s, it corresponds to the displacement from O to P.
>
> In simplified terms, position is used in reference to the location of a 'child' entity within a two-dimensional or three-dimensional space, the boundaries of which are referred to as the 'container' or 'parent'.

And hence used in questions regarding other languages as well.

This seems to be ambiguous.

---

Most of the CSS questions are wrongly(*If I'm right*) tagged with [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position). There is already [a burninate request for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269550/burninate-positioning) [positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/positioning), Stating it is too general...

Is [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position) worthy of existence? What is the correct action to be taken here..?

Comment: Long ago I was working to remove all the non-CSS questions from these tags so the rest could be merged into [tag:css-position] but never finished.